# Chess challenge #3: Pinned knights

Tags: tactics, problems

Here it is a new chess problem much more difficult than the previous one. The diagram position is the following:

```
[fen "3rr2k/6pp/p2q1p2/5P2/3Nb3/1P1RQ1NP/6P1/7K w - - 0 1"]
```

Black has just played Bxe4 but that is not a good choice. **How should White continue in this position?**

I took this problem from the [Chess Tactics Server.](http://chess.emrald.net/index.php) I hope this takes more time to be solved than the previous one.

EDIT:

> After Nxe4 Black plays Qd4 instead of Qe4, giving White the choice of playing a powerful movement.

Comment: Hehe Chess Tactics Server is brutal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attempting to answer the revised puzzle:

> 1.Nxe4 Qd5 2.Qg3 with the threat of 3 Ne6 winning due to double threat (4 Qxg7 and discovered attack from the Rd3).  White still carries out this threat if Black answers 2.Qg3 with either Qxe4 or Rxe4.  Presumably this is strong enough that the engines didn't even let Black answer 1.Nxe4 with Qd5.  Note that this tactic also depends on Qg3's access to d3 (after Qxe4 3 Ne6 Qxe6 4 fxe6 Rxd3) and the 8th rank (for Qxe4 3 Ne6 Rxe6 4 Rxd8+ Re8 5 Qb8!).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would play:

> 1. Nxe4 (removes the threat to the Rook) Qe5 (pins the knight) 2. Ne6 (discovered attack to weaken the back rank) Rxd3 3. Qxd3 Qxf5 4. N6c5 (note the e4 knight cannot be taken by the Rook due to the weak back rank). It is nominally even material (2 knights vs. Rook and Pawn), but White has much more active pieces.

Comment: I'm stumped! After a lot of brain wracking, I put the problem into an engine and got the same line too. I'm tempted to ask for a clue (which you could include in a spoiler tag by editing the question. The spoiler tag syntax is >! Here is a clue!).

Comment: The problem with the solution that you're giving (which is great) is that the second move played by black is not the move that it plays in the puzzle, I've edited the question to reflect that.